# Error 1054, not recognizing first select column

Tags: php, mysql

I am coding a php page off of an mySQL database and the table is fully built with all the columns I am trying to have viewed on a website, but my select statement is returning an error.  It won't recognize the first column I input.  I've taken out the "lastname" search and had it just start with "firstname" and had the same problem.  On another use of this table I am also having trouble inputting stuff into the first column.  Am I forming my statement wrong or something?

I am using a common functions php with this code:

```
function connectDatabase() {
    require('../DBtest.php');

    $host     = 'localhost';
    $userid   = '7an7';
    $password = '7dl7';

    $db = mysql_perry_pconnect($host, $userid, $password);

    if (!$db) {
        print "<h1>Unable to Connect to MySQL</h1>";
        exit;
    }

    $dbname = '7phpmysql7';
    $dbtest = mysql_perry_select_db($dbname);

    if (!$dbtest) {
        print "<h1>Unable to Select the Database</h1>";
    }

    return $db;
}

function selectResults($statement) {

    $output      = "";
    $outputArray = array();

    $db = connectDatabase();

    if ($db) {
        $result = mysql_query($statement);

        if (!$result) {
            $output .= "ERROR";
            $output .= "<br /><font color=red>MySQL No: " . mysql_errno();
            $output .= "<br />MySQL Error: " . mysql_error();
            $output .= "<br />SQL Statement: " . $statement;
            $output .= "<br />MySQL Affected Rows: " . mysql_affected_rows() . "</font><br />";

            array_push($outputArray, $output);
        } else {

            $numresults = mysql_num_rows($result);

            array_push($outputArray, $numresults);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $numresults; $i++) {
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                array_push($outputArray, $row);
            }
        }
    } else {

        array_push($outputArray, 'ERROR-No DB Connection');
    }

    return $outputArray;
}
```

Then local code that is utilizing the common functions is:

```
<?php
include "king_common_functions.php";

viewGuestbook();

//****************************************************************
//Display Admin Guestbook Data (All Submissions)
//****************************************************************

function viewGuestbook() {
    $outputDisplay = "";
    $myrowcount    = 0;

    $statement = "SELECT lastname, firstname, contact_type, contact_info, city, comments, date_added";
    $statement .= "FROM u1585_Guestbook ";
    $statement .= "ORDER BY lastname ";

    $sqlResults = selectResults($statement);

    $error_or_rows = $sqlResults[0];


    if (substr($error_or_rows, 0, 5) == 'ERROR') {
        print "<br />Error on DB";
        print $error_or_rows;
    } else {
        $arraySize = $error_or_rows;

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $error_or_rows; $i++) {
            $lastname     = $sqlResults[$i]['lastname'];
            $firstname    = $sqlResults[$i]['firstname'];
            $contact_type = $sqlResults[$i]['contact_type'];
            $contact_info = $sqlResults[$i]['contact_info'];
            $city         = $sqlResults[$i]['city'];
            $comments     = $sqlResults[$i]['comments'];
            $date_added   = $sqlResults[$i]['date_added'];

            $outputDisplay = "<h3>View Guestbook:</h3>";
            $outputDisplay .= '<table border=1 style="color: black;">';
            $outputDisplay .= '<tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Contact Type</th><th>Contact Info</th>';
            $outputDisplay .= '<th>City</th><th>Comments</th><th>Date Added</th></tr>';

            $numresults = mysql_num_rows($sqlResults);

            for ($j = 0; $j < $numresults; $j++) {
                if (!($j % 2) == 0) {
                    $outputDisplay .= "<tr style=\"background-color: #F5DEB3;\">";
                } else {
                    $outputDisplay .= "<tr style=\"background-color: white;\">";
                }

                $myrowcount++;

                $outputDisplay .= "<td>" . $lastname . "</td>";
                $outputDisplay .= "<td>" . $firstname . "</td>";
                $outputDisplay .= "<td>" . $contact_type . "</td>";
                $outputDisplay .= "<td>" . $contact_info . "</td>";
                $outputDisplay .= "<td>" . $city . "</td>";
                $outputDisplay .= "<td>" . $comments . "</td>";
                $outputDisplay .= "<td>" . $date_added . "</td>";
                $outputDisplay .= "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }

    $outputDisplay .= "</table>";
    $outputDisplay .= "<br /><br /><b>Number of Rows in Results: $myrowcount </b><br /><br />";
    print $outputDisplay;
}
```

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE u1585_Guestbook (
    guest_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    lastname varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    firstname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    contact_type varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    contact_info varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    city varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    comments varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    date_added date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (guest_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Will look into those.  Just learning now and being taught mySQL...will look to the future.

Comment: FYI, if your code is formatted properly in your editor (or IDE), a copy-paste will work fine, then you can just highlight the code and click the `{}` button in the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: What exactly is the error message you receive? Please add it to the end of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your code. If you're having an issue with a query, `echo` it to the screen. In your case (just by looking at your code), the query you pass (`$statement`) looks like this:

> SELECT lastname, firstname, contact_type, contact_info, city,
>   comments, date_addedFROM u1585_Guestbook ORDER BY lastname

In PHP, you can define a string over multiple lines in order to avoid such mistakes. Like so:

```
<?php
.
.
.
$statement = "SELECT lastname, firstname, contact_type, contact_info, city, comments, date_added
    FROM u1585_Guestbook 
    ORDER BY lastname ";
```

**UPDATE:**

In response to your comments below, I would recommend using PDO to set up your query:

```
//connect to DB
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

// prepare your statement
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO u1585_guestbook(lastname, firstname, contact_type, contact_info, city, comments, date_added) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$data = array($mylastname, $myfirstname, $mycontact_type, $mycontactinfo, $mycity, $mycomments, $mydate);

// execute your statement
$query->execute($data);
```

[Take a look at this overview to learn more about PDO.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) It's pretty awesome.

Comment: Thanks! I am having trouble in a different section in the same table with an insert with this statement:  $statement = "insert into u1585_guestbook (lastname, firstname, contact_type, contact_info, city, comments, date_added)
 values ('".$mylastname."', '".$myfirstname."', '".$mycontact_type."', '".$mycontactinfo."', '".$mycity."', '".$mycomments."', '".$mydate."')";

Comment: It is not inputting into the first field that is listed.  Right now it pushes all the data over one column.  The last name goes into first, first goes into contact type, contact info into city, comments disappears and date added is fine.

Comment: @Brad updated my answer to help with your `insert` problem. I can't guarantee that this will fix your problem, but it should work.